# Is there a way to get last updates of associated models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `Car` model, which is associated with many other models. How can I check updated_at of all associated models and get the latest of them, something like:

> Car door was updated at "this time"

I have many associations in my model so getting each one of them and comparing is not efficient. If there is a better way please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: The answer for that is just for a single relation, I have about 16 reltations, as I mentioned above checking each of them and then comparing wouldn't be efficient. IF there is a better way I would prefer to go with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [touch](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch) method here. Basically, touch is used to update the `updated_at` field of a record. For example, `Car.last.touch` would set the `updated_at` field of the last `Car` record to the current time. 
However, `touch` can also be used with relations, to trigger the `touch` method on the associated object. So, in your case something like this may work:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :corporation, touch: true
end

class Door < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car, touch: true
end

# Door updation triggers updated_at of parent as well
@door = Door.last
@door.updated_at = DateTime.now
@door.save! # Updates updated_at of corresponding car record as well
```

In the example above, `@door.touch` could also have been used to update the `updated_at` of the corresponding parent `Car` record.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped alot.